# groovy: variable scope in closures in the super class (MissingPropertyException)

Tags: groovy, scope, closures, superclass

I have the impression that closures run as the actual class being called (instead of the implementing super class) and thus break when some variables are not visible (e.g. private in the super class).

For example

```
package comp.ds.GenericTest2

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class ClosureScopeC {
        private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
        private int accessThisPrivateVariable = 0;

        void add(String a) {
                list.add(a)
                println("before ${accessThisPrivateVariable} ${this.class.name}")
                // do something with a closure
                list.each {String it ->
                        if (it == a) {
                                // accessThisPrivateVariable belongs to ClosureScopeC
                                accessThisPrivateVariable++
                        }
                }
                println("after ${accessThisPrivateVariable}")
        }
}

// this works fine
a = new ClosureScopeC()
a.add("abc")
a.add("abc")

// child class
class ClosureScopeD extends ClosureScopeC {
        void doSomething(String obj) {
                this.add(obj)
        }
}

b = new ClosureScopeD()

// THIS THROWS groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: accessThisPrivateVariable for class: comp.ds.GenericTest2.ClosureScopeD
b.doSomething("abc")
```

The last line throws a MissingPropertyException: the child class calls the "add" method of the super class, which executes the "each" closure, which uses the "accessThisPrivateVariable".

I am new to groovy, so I think there must be an easy way to do this, because otherwise it seems that closures completely break the encapsulation of the private implementation done in the super class ... this seems to be a very common need (super class implementation referencing its own private variables)

I am using groovy 2.1.3

Comment: As with your other question, this is probably better asked on the groovy-user mailing list

Comment: Ok, thanks Tim, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a good reference describing how Groovy variable scopes work and applies to your situation: [Closure in groovy cannot use private field when called from extending class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071667/closure-in-groovy-cannot-use-private-field-when-called-from-extending-class)

From the above link, I realized that since you have declared `accessThisPrivateVariable` as private, Groovy would not auto-generate a getter/setter for the variable. Remember, even in Java, private variables are not accessible directly by sub-classes.

Changing your code to explicitly add  the getter/setters, solved the issue:

```
package com.test
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class ClosureScopeC {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
    private int accessThisPrivateVariable = 0;

    int getAccessThisPrivateVariable() { accessThisPrivateVariable }
    void setAccessThisPrivateVariable(int value ){this.accessThisPrivateVariable = value}

    void add(String a) {
        list.add(a)
        println("before ${accessThisPrivateVariable} ${this.class.name}")
        // do something with a closure
        list.each {String it ->
            if (it == a) {
                 // accessThisPrivateVariable belongs to ClosureScopeC
                accessThisPrivateVariable++
            }
        }
        println("after ${accessThisPrivateVariable}")
    }
}

// this works fine
a = new ClosureScopeC()
a.add("abc")
a.add("abc")

// child class
class ClosureScopeD extends ClosureScopeC {
    void doSomething(String obj) {
        super.add(obj)
    }
}

b = new ClosureScopeD()
b.doSomething("abc")
```

There is a simpler way, just make the access modifier (should rename the property really) to protected, so the sub-class has access to the property.. problem solved.

```
protected int accessThisProtectedVariable
```

To clarify on your statement of concern that Groovy possibly has broken encapsulation: rest assured it hasn't.

By declaring a field as private, Groovy is preserving encapsulation by intentionally suspending automatic generation of the public getter/setter. Once private, you are now responsible and in full control of how or if there is a way for sub-classes (protected) or all classes of objects (public) to gain access to the field by explicitly adding methods - if that makes sense.

Remember that by convention, Groovy ALWAYS calls a getter or setter when your codes references the field. So, a statement like:

```
def f = obj.someField
```

will actually invoke the `obj.getSomeField()` method. 
Likewise:

```
obj.someField = 5
```

will invoke the `obj.setSomeField(5)` method.