# Closure in groovy cannot use private field when called from extending class

Tags: inheritance, groovy, closures

I have a class in groovy, where I have a private field, and a method. In the method, I call http service, and pass a closure there to handle the response. Something like this:

```
class WebUiRestRequestSender {

    private String jSessionIdCookie

    def login(String username, String password) {
        //...
        httpClient.post(
            path: login,
            body: parameters,
            requestContentType : URLENC
        )  { resp, reader ->
            jSessionIdCookie = getSessionCookie(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I create object of this class and call this method. However, when I  inherit from this class, and try to call the method from inheriting class, I'm getting error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jSessionIdCookie for class: ResellerWebUiRestRequestSender
```

Why is that? Why superclass method cannot see property defined in superclass in Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

Default access modifier in Groovy is `public`, which helps in creating POGOs seamlessly as Groovy adds the accessor methods automatically at class generation.

When the access modifier is changed to `private`, groovy does not create any accessor method for that property. In order to access that private property as a read-only property 
`getJSessionIdCookie()` method has to be added to the base class.

```
getJSessionIdCookie() { jSessionIdCookie }
```

Now, when you access `jSessionIdCookie` in sub-class, `getProperty` metaclass implementation will invoke the above getter method instead.

Comment: But I don't access jSessionIdCookie from subclass? The method I'm calling, the field and the closure are in superclass.